# Как сделать разный фон одинаковым блокам?

Tags: html, css, scss

В вёрстке есть список из 8 разных блоков, стилизация у элементов абсолютно одинаковая, за исключением разного фона у каждого. Как их можно залить не добавляя 8 псевдоклассов на каждый из них?

[image: выглядит это примерно так]

Comment: задать 8 разных правил, не используя 8 разных селекторов? странный вопрос, а, главное, непонятно в чем его причина? проблема XY

Comment: Можно через JS сделать. Получить коллекцию блоков. Записать в массив нужные цвета.  И запустить  через цикл добавление бэкграунда с цветом (colors[i], blocks[i])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: var(--bg);
}

.my-class {
  background: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div style="--bg: #fff;"></div>
<div style="--bg: #eee;"></div>
<div style="--bg: #ddd;"></div>
<div style="--bg: #ccc;"></div>
<div style="--bg: #bbb;"></div>
<div style="--bg: #aaa;"></div>
<div style="--bg: #999;"></div>
<div style="--bg: #888;"></div>
<div class="my-class" style="--bg: #f00;"></div>
```

Comment: и переопределять с important, как единственный выход из катастрофы выглядит, но работает

Comment: Таково ТЗ, хозяин барин) Спасибо всем!

Comment: @highpassion, если переопределять переменную, то да, придется использовать important. Но переопределить можно background (добавил в ответ). К сожалению, при такой постановке задачи вариантов не много.

Comment: @DanielMaslov дело не в тз, а в том, что ваш код становится противным для поддержки в дальнейшем из-за этих прихотей, у адекватных технически подкованных людей в тз обычно обьясняется, зачем этот цирк

Comment: @UserTest013 да, вы правы, можно и селекторами переопределять, но как я понял в задаче не до разных селекторов